# Beamer: subsections all in one line, with dashes in-between

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

How can I list the subsections in the table of contents with dashes in between? I managed to get dashes in-between but also behind the last subsection in the code below. The extra dash does not seem to be easily removable using my approach.

(Trust me, in my non-minimal working example, this actually looks nice.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\inserttocsubsection \hspace{0.5em}$-$\hspace{-0.5em} }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{This }
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Is }
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{A }
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Minimal}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Working}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Example}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The solution of samcarter fixed my approach but has problems with subsection highlighting. See [Beamer: subsections all in one line, with dashes in-between and proper highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464146/beamer-subsections-all-in-one-line-with-dashes-in-between-and-proper-highlight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it the other way round:

instead of removing the dash after the last subsection, place them before the subsections, because it is much easier to test if the subsection number is equal to 1

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\ifnum\inserttocsubsectionnumber>1
    $-$\hspace{0.5em}%
\fi
\inserttocsubsection}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Section}
\subsection{This}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Is}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{A}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Minimal}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Working}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Example}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect fix of my approach; unfortunately I noticed an immediate follow-up problem of this approach with highlighting of the current subsection. If you are interested, I describe the problem in a new section of the question.

Comment: @Bananach Maybe it would be better to ask this as a new question -- this seems to be actually quite tricky

Comment: done, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464146/beamer-subsections-all-in-one-line-with-dashes-in-between-and-proper-highlight