# Beamer: subsections all in one line, with dashes in-between and proper highlighting

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

How can I list the subsections in the table of contents with dashes in between? I found a partial solution (thanks to samcarter, in a previous question), however when the table of contents is displayed at the beginning of a subsection, the dashes are highlighted as well.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\ifnum\inserttocsubsectionnumber>1
    $-$\hspace{0.5em}%
\fi
\inserttocsubsection}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{This}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Is}
\tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=show/shaded]
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{A}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Minimal}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Working}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Example}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit hacky, not sure what the following workaround will break...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\colorlet{foo}{black}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\ifnum\inserttocsubsectionnumber>1
    {%
        \color{black!20}%
        $-$\hspace{0.5em}%
    }%
\fi
\textcolor{foo}{\inserttocsubsection}}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc shaded}{%
%\begin{colormixin}{20!parent.bg}
\begingroup%
\colorlet{foo}{black!20}%
\usebeamertemplate{subsection in toc}%
%\end{colormixin}
\endgroup%
\unskip}


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{This}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Is}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=show/shaded]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{A}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Minimal}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Working}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Example}
\begin{frame}{test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]